# key value pairs from tuple in python

Tags: python, django, web.py

how can I convert a tuple into a key value pairs dynamically?

Let's say I have:

```
tuple = ('name1','value1','name2','value2','name3','value3')
```

I want to put it into a dictionary:

```
dictionary = { name1 : value1, name2 : value2, name3 : value3 )
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is an odd number of items in your tuple? Also, you don't want to use `tuple` as a variable name...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Convert the tuple to key-value pairs and let the `dict` constructor build a dictionary:

```
it = iter(tuple_)
dictionary = dict(zip(it, it))
```

The `zip(it, it)` idiom produces pairs of items from an otherwise flat iterable, providing a sequence of pairs that can be passed to the `dict` constructor. A generalization of this is available as the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the itertools documentation.

If the input is sufficiently large, replace `zip` with `itertools.izip` to avoid allocating a temporary list. Unlike expressions based on mapping `t[i]` to `[i + 1]`, the above will work on any iterable, not only on sequences.

Comment: +1. Love this solution. For some reason, I always assumed `zip()` wouldn't consume its arguments in alternating order.

Comment: @JoelCornett `zip` doesn't really care, it just consumes the iterables left to right. (Left-to-right consumption is actually [guaranteed in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) precisely to make this idiom work.)

Comment: BTW the grouping idiom can be, and frequently is, expressed as a one-liner: `dict(zip(*[iter(tuple)] * 2))`. The one-liner form is much harder to understand, so I refrained from using it here.

Comment: How about `zip(*repeat(iter(tuple_), 2)`?

Comment: @JoelCornett It works just fine, but it requires an additional import from `itertools`, so I don't see the benefit over `[iter(t)] * 2` or `(iter(t),) * 2`. The simple `zip(it, it)` still seems the clearest expression of the idea, at the cost of introducing a local variable. (And at the cost of providing temptation for an overzealous reviewer to "optimize" `zip(it, it)` into `zip(t, t)`, which actually breaks the code!)

Answer (score 3):

```
dictionary = {tuple[i]: tuple[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(tuple), 2)}
```

Another simple way :

```
dictionary = dict(zip(tuple[::2],tuple[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

just do a simple loop.

```
my_dic = {}
tuple = ('name1','value1','name2','value2','name3','value3')
if len(tuple) % 2 == 1:
    my_dic[tuple[-1]] = None
for i in range(0, len(tuple) - 1, 2):
    my_dic[tuple[i]] = tuple[i + 1]
print my_dic
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tuple = ('name1','value1','name2','value2','name3','value3')
d = {}
for i in range(0, len(tuple), 2):
    d[tuple[i]] = tuple[i+1]
print d
```